# MySQL - Turkey/Istanbul Daylight Saving Time Change

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds, aws, timezone

Until this year Turkey was using daylight saving time, staying UTC+2 on winter period, UTC+3 on summer. This year it is decided to stay only in UTC+3.

Our DateTime's are persisted on MySQL (5.26.34) db (on AWS) was using UTC timezone.

When i try to use CONVERT_TZ(DateTime, UTC, EUROPE/ISTANBUL) for recent datetime -lets say- 2016-11-21 00:00 it tries to convert according to UTC+2, whereas it suppose to be UTC+3.

When i would tried to convert 2015-11-21 00:00 -last year- it suppose to convert according to UTC+2, since Turkey was in UTC+2 at that time.

I Found an announcement on AWS forum[1], advicing to use Moscow timezone, which is not an option for us since Turkey's timezone situation is unique and our DateTime's are saved in the form of UTC0.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=4115

Comment: I think you just need to update tzdata info. The latest releases have this change. See a similar question at ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/804403/disable-daylight-saving-time-dst-changes-in-linux

Comment: DST sucks; I wish we could get rid of it worldwide.  We use the excuse that it helps the farmers.  Bull.  A cow does not look at the clock to decide that is is milking time.

Answer (score 0):

`DATETIME` is like a picture of a clock.  There is no going back to fix it.  A `DATETIME` column reflects what the user would see on a clock at the time he/she does the `INSERT`.

`TIMESTAMP` is stored internally as UTC, but converted going in and going out.  So, *if* the timezone is set correctly, and if the tz table is correct, `TIMESTAMP` always reflects a point of time in the cosmos.

So, in addition to getting the tz code 'right', and setting the timezone correctly, use the 'right' datatype.

Comment: it is not like we saved our datetime wrong in db. errorneous part is timezone info of mysql, you should read the question before answering.